# Strange behaviour in WordPress MySQL insert of JSON encoded data

Tags: php, mysql, json, encoding, utf-8

I'm looking at both my code and my result and I don't see any glaring error, so I thought it could be useful to have a few extra sets of eyes look it over.

I have a custom PayPal IPN listener that updates a transaction table in the database. I deployed it Friday before leaving work, and after returning today it seems to be working *mostly* correctly; but I would like to figure out why one insert behaved strangely.

Here's a capture of the inserts which happened over the weekend:
[image: PayPal IPN log]

As you can see, the intended JSON value for the `log` column of the 4th transaction is empty. I find it strange because the value of the `transaction_id` column is being parsed from the same array.

Here is the relevant db `insert` code:

```
// Generate valid IPN log
private function generateIpnLog () {
    global $wpdb;

    // prepare log
    $array_log = [];
    $array_log['verified'] = true;
    $array_log['ipn_response'] = (isset($this->PayPal_Response)) ? : 'Error reading from POST array';

    // Parse transaction ID
    $transaction_id = (isset($this->PayPal_Response['txn_id'])) ? $this->PayPal_Response['txn_id'] : null;

    // Generate log
    $log = json_encode($array_log);

    // Update DB
    $wpdb->insert(
        'log_paypal',
        [
            'transaction_id'    => ($transaction_id) ? $transaction_id : 'Error getting transaction ID',
            'log' => ($log) ? $log : 'Error generating transaction log'
        ],
        [
            '%s',
            '%s'
        ]
    );

    // json log response
    $this->json_return = $log;
}
```

Seeing as the transaction id is parsed fine from the PayPal response, and because we know `$array_log['verified']` has an explictly declared value my guess is there must be a problem with `json_encode($array_log)`.

I also checked the data from PayPal IPN history of the PayPal account in question, and can verify there isn't anything different about the way the data is being formed in the null `log` column vs the others.

Anyone have an idea about what could be happening in this instance?

Comment: If I got it right, you could see what `log` (the `$array_log`) should have been in the empty row?  You should edit it in, it's pretty relevant.

Comment: @ishegg I'm not sure what your question is, but if you are asking if I can manually update the row with the IPN data - yes I can, and already have. But it's obviously not helpful for the long term.

Comment: No, I mean, can you manually reconstruct `$array_log`, as to see why it didn't encode correctly?

Comment: Oh, hrmm I suppose I might be able to try that, but I am not sure it will work. I don't think the data as given in the PayPal IPN history comes in the same format as what it posts to my server. It's worth a try though, so I will. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it. There are Swedish vowels in the data so there's a chance the DB charset is rejecting the data

Comment: That's absolutely it. You need to UTF-8 encode it. And, `json_encode()` doesn't return `false` on error, which is why it didn't set "Error" in log, just NULL. You can use `json_last_error()` for further debugging this.

Comment: Ah okay, I definitely feel we're on to something here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hope you get to the bottom of it! Sidenote: I think you're not setting the `ipn_response` element to anything? `$array_log['ipn_response'] = (isset($this->PayPal_Response)) ? : 'Error reading from POST array';
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153633/discussion-between-drewt-and-ishegg).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ishegg it was an encoding issue since PayPal IPN uses `windows-1252` encoding and the DB field was encoded in `UTF-8`.

It was easy to fix in this case since the PayPal return data is not nested / multidimensional (see below).

**Called in an earlier function after a PayPal IPN entry is cryptographically verified by the cert chain:**

```
// Process IPN response
$this->PayPal_Response = $this->processIpn();
```

**Then, the function itself:**

```
// Manipulate IPN response and prepare  
// for database update and log
private function processIpn () {
    // Response ref.
    $response = $this->post_array;

    if ( isset($response['charset']) ) {
        if ($response['charset'] == "windows-1252") {
            foreach ($response as $key => $ipn_value) {
                $response[$key] = mb_convert_encoding($ipn_value, 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1252');
            }
        }
    }
    return $response;
}
```